# How to install listings package in Kubuntu for LaTeX?

Tags: package-management, kubuntu, latex

I installed LaTeX on my Kubuntu with those commands:

```
sudo apt-get install abntex
sudo apt-get install texmaker
sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-base texlive-latex-extra texlive-latex-recommended texlive-fonts-recommended texmaker
```

but I also need to use `listings` package for my assignment paper. How to install `listings` package for LaTeX here?

Comment: Might be best suitable on http://tex.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If the listings package was not missing, then what was the problem? Any error message?

Comment: @mtk: Even better: http://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I recommend you to use `apt-file` to search for the package that contains a specific file.

If you invoke

```
apt-file search listings.sty
```

you should find the package that contains `listings`.

On my system it's contained in `texlive-latex-recommended` that you have already installed.

To play it safe i would execute

```
texhash
```

to update latex's directory tree.

If you can't get it working after that i'm pretty sure that something else is wrong.

Comment: For me, `apt-get install texlive-latex-recommended` was the solution. Thanks for the tip about `apt-file`!

Answer (score 0):

The solution proposed by the author or the question:

> Ok it turned out that `listings` wasn't missing it was something
> different which caused the problem. I found a solution:
>
> ```
> mkdir -p /usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/floatflt
> cd /usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/floatflt
> rm -f floatflt.* float*.tex
> wget http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/floatflt/floatflt.ins
> wget http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/floatflt/floatflt.dtx
> latex floatflt.ins
> texhash /usr/share/texmf-texlive
> ```